# Как удалить из файла строки или ограничение на количество строк в файле?

Tags: строки, java, файлы

Есть задача "прокрутки" данных вида-строк, через файл. В файле должно быть не больше 1000 строк. Когда файл переполняется, старые строки стираются (сверху).

Кроме варианта, загрузить данные, удалить файл, сохранить данные какие ещё есть? Лучше кодом.

Comment: - открываем файл. считаем количество строк (N)
- количество строк для удаления (D) = N + C - 1000, (C) - количество строк которые надо добавить.
- открываем файл. удаляем первых "С" строк
- открываем файл для аппенд. 

если заранее не известно сколько строк будет дописано в файл то можно сначала аппендить к файлу а потом уже удалять

Comment: - открываем файл. удаляем первых "С" строк  
а не подскажите какой именно командой или каким из способов вы имели ввиду?

Comment: как такового удаления нету. потому что мы работаем с потоками (непрерывными наборами данных). вам надо открывать поток для чтения и записи на одном файле. т.е в цикле делаете считывание и запись (буферизированые). надо удалить 5 первых строк, - пропускаете их в цикле. пример:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/522717/java/java/replacing-content-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377279/java-find-a-line-in-a-file-and-remove) пример есть небольшой, а [тут](http://www.intuit.ru/department/pl/javapl/15/) можно про `java io` почитать, + [много](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-io-tutorials/) примеров.